# Get location of control in foreign window

Tags: vb.net, ime

I'm trying to make a **Net IME keyboard application**. This app will suggest me relevant topics when typing or searching. But I can't get the location of an active textbox control from other applications.

The `FindWindowEx` function works though, but I'm looking for the location of an active textbox so i can change the location of the suggestion control to that textbox. Thanks!

```
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Integer, ByVal hWnd2 As Integer, ByVal lpsz1 As String,
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Integer
```

Comment: You can use UI Automation for this. The [AutomationElement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement) class provides the [TryGetClickablePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.trygetclickablepoint) method (returns a Point struct inside the Element/Control) and the object referenced by `AutomationElement.Current` provides the [BoundingRectangle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationelementinformation.boundingrectangle) property.

Comment: The `AutomationElement.SetFocus()` method can move the focus to an Element/Control. The `AutomationElement.Current.IsOffScreen` property can be used to determine whether the control is currently visible.

Comment: Hi Jimi! I've managed to learn the basics and have it working. My problem now is it won't work on chrome. A little bit of research i found out it's not possible with UIAutomation, however it does work if added a parameter chrome --force-renderer-accessibility, But i don't want the users to go through all the trouble just to use the software.. Any other methods or ways to avoid this problem?